# Microsoft Translator Text API doesn't work

Tags: api, azure, translate, bing

I want to use Microsoft Translator API but I am unable to use it.

I created a Microsoft Azure account as specified in the documentation (http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html) and I created a resource.

When I call the web service to get an access toke, every time I get an exception because a time out..

This is my code (it's Apex, similar to Java) :

```
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Length', '3495');
req.setEndpoint('https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken?Subscription-Key=[myAPIKey]');
req.setTimeout(20000);
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

If I remove my API key or I the content length from the header, I get an error from Microsoft.

Do you know why I get this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fin now.

I edit my code and it is ok :

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setEndpoint(theURL);
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/xml');
Http binding = new Http();
HttpResponse res = binding.send(req);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should replace [myAPIKey] with the right key. You can get it through https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services

[image]

**EDIT**
The answer above is related to GET operations. For POST, you should include the 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' header:

```
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Length', '3495');
req.setHeader('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key', '[INSERT_HERE_YOUR_TOKEN]');
req.setEndpoint('https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken');
req.setTimeout(20000);
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

Comment: Ok but why it works if I use that online token authentication service (http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/oauth-token.html) with the input field?

Comment: Thank you for your help.

I already get for a key, why should I request another?
And for my case, which one have I to take please?
I don't see Translator API.

Aurélien